# Why my neural network with radial neuron do not train?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, feed-forward

Good night, everyone,

I want to fit the curve (y=exp(-(x-30).^2)) of the image in the hyperlink below using a neural network in matlab. For this, i want to use a feedfoward network with radial basis neuron.

[image]

I've wrote a code, but it's not working and i can't understand why.

```
x=[10:0.1:40];
y=exp(-(x-30).^2);

plot(x,y)

nN=[1];

net = feedforwardnet(nN,'traingd');
net.trainParam.epochs=50000;

net.trainParam.lr = 0.01;
net.trainParam.min_grad=0;
net.trainParam.max_fail=15;


net.divideParam.trainRatio = 60/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 20/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 20/100;


net.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'radbas';
net.layers{2}.transferFcn = 'purelin';



net = configure(net, x, y);

net.iw{1,1}=30;

net.biasConnect=[1; 1];
net.inputConnect=[1; 0];
net.layerConnect=[0 0;1 0];
net.outputConnect=[0 1];


net.inputWeights{1,1}.weightFcn='dist';
net.layers{1}.netInputFcn='netprod';


net.inputWeights{1,1}.learnFcn='learngd';
net.layerWeights{2,1}.learnFcn='learngd';
net.biases{:}.learnFcn='learngd';


[net,tr] = train(net,x,y);
yFinal = net(x);

plot(x,y,'.',x,yFinal,'o')
```

I'm using backpropagation to training the neural network. I've used one hidden layer with one neuron with transfer function equal to radbas and with dist how weight function. The output layer has one neuron with transfer function equal to pureline and the weight function is dotprod. When i use dotprod how the weight function of  the input of the neuron in the hidden layer, the network trains properly. (Image 2)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ldmr8.png)

But i need to use 'dist' and when i use dist how the weight function, the neural network don't learn (image 3). If you type 'help nnweight' you will see that 'dist' is one of the possibles weight functions. I can not undertand why it don't work.

[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vkvp8.png)

Someone could, please, help me?
Thank you so much.

Comment: This question is very badly presented. "It's not working" without more information is nearly useless :-/. While neural networks surely can do stuff like that, architecture and regulization should be very very important!

Comment: I'm using backpropagation to training the neural network. I've used one hidden layer with one neuron with transfer function equal to radbas and with dist how weight function. The output layer has one neuron with transfer function equal to pureline and the weight function is dotprod. When i use dotprod how the weight function of  the input of the neuron in the hidden layer, the network trains properly, but i need to use dist and when i use dist how the weight function, the neural network don't learn. If you type 'help nnweight' you will see that 'dist' is one of the possibles weight functions

Comment: I can not undertand why it don't work.